# Netbeans class' method not recognized

Tags: java

I'm having a fairly odd problem with Netbeans.

I'm trying to calculate the sum of an ArrayList, but I am not able to call the method `public int sumOfHand()` onto my `this.hands` variable.

I've restarted Netbeans numerous times, created new classes and tried to calculate the sum using the .reduce() method using streams, but none of it helped.
Thanks for any suggestion!

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Hand implements Comparable<Hand>{
    public ArrayList<Card> hands;
    
    public Hand() {
        this.hands = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void add(Card card) {
        this.hands.add(card);
    }
    
    public void print() {
        this.hands.forEach(crd -> {System.out.println(crd);});
    }
    
    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(this.hands, (crd1, crd2) -> crd1.compareTo(crd2));
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Hand otherHand) {
       // sumOfHand() not recognized here, 'Cannot find symbol'
       return this.hands.sumOfHand() - otherHand.sumOfHand();
    }
               
    public int sumOfHand() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Card tc : this.hands) {
            sum += tc.getValue();
        }
        return sum; 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: For years, years and years to come, while you gather experience and knowledge - just assume that when Netbeans says "something is wrong" - then it's actually wrong. Figuring out why it's wrong - and understanding the error messages - is an important learning experience. In this case - there is no `sumOfHand` method on `ArrayList<Card>`. It's directly on `this`.

Comment: Lesson #2: It would probably help you understand your own code better if you used meaningful names for the variables.  A `Hand` of cards does not consist of `hands`. It consists of `cards`.  "Little" things like using correct variable names will help you spot when you are trying to do something nonsensical ... rather than wasting your time chasing after non-existent problems in the tools (e.g. Netbeans) that you are trying to use.

Comment: @fdreger Thank you very much for the explanation, I feel a lot dumber now.

Comment: @StephenC I'm sorry, but the snippet of the code you see is from the MOOC.fi Java course and the names of the classes are already prescribed.

Comment: It is not the name of the class that is the problem.  It is this: `public ArrayList<Card> hands;`.  Why do you call a list of `Card` objects `hands`??  (I can't imagine that the MOOC did that ...)

Comment: Well, I didn't think I would come across such a problem, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a `int sumOfHand()` of `this.hands` as `hands` is an ArrayList.class and `int sumOfHand()` is a method of Hand.class. To call this method you need to use `this.sumOfHands()` inside your Hand.class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did not see the wood for the trees!